# SOLR :Ignoring bad rows while indexing CSV using POST

Tags: csv, unix, post, solr, lucene

I am trying to index a large file(1.5 gb with 6 million rows) to solr-6.3.0 using POST tool.I am getting an IO Error on a particular row using the following command.I am using ubuntu 16.04

```
bin/post -c mycore3 /home/shubham/combined.csv
```

I want to skip such rows and want to keep on indexing the rest of the rows.Please help out.Below is the error log.Name of the the core is mycore3

```
java -classpath /opt/solr-6.3.0/dist/solr-core-6.3.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=mycore3 -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool /home/shubham/combined.csv
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore3/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file combined.csv (text/csv) to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore3/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">6977</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str></lst><str name="msg">CSVLoader: input=null, line=94221,expected 14 values but got 13
    values={'Plot No-941','SS II Room','R.F.Naik High School, Junior and Senior College','','400709','','','Sector 8','','','Nueva Bombay','Bombay/Bombaim','IND',}</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore3/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore3/update...
Time spent: 0:01:11.862
```

Out of 1.1 gb ,26 mb has been indexed before the error broke out

[Solr admin dashboard for mycore3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnod5.png)

As requested these are the first few rows of the csv file

```
HouseNumber,BuildingName,Landmark,Street,Postcode,Block,DependentLocality,SubLocality,Locality,SubMunicipality,Town,District,State,Country
40E,,,,641006,,,,Poosari Palayam,Poosari Palayam,Coimbatore,Coimbatore,Tamil Nadu,IND
45,Ganesh Illam,,,641027,,,,Sanganur,Sanganur,Coimbatore,Coimbatore,Tamil Nadu,IND
131,,,,641037,,Jayasimma Puram,,Papanaicker Palyam,Papanaicker Palyam,Coimbatore,Coimbatore,Tamil Nadu,IND
4,Ratna Niwas,,,641670,,Rajiv Gandhi Nagar,,Uppili Palayam,Uppili Palayam,Coimbatore,Coimbatore,Tamil Nadu,IND
```

Comment: could you show first couple of rows in csv?

Comment: there is no way to skip error lines, could you fix it?

Comment: No I wasn't ,can you advise a shorter way  ?